# Placing a view directly on top of another of the same size

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, uiview-hierarchy

Ok, first what i'm trying to achieve:

A background video with interactive text over the top.

This text is being generated in the code i've written and is being presented in a UIView. The video is being played in an AVPlayerController, embedded in a UIContainerView.

My original plan was to set the UIView's width, height, and top to be equal to the UIContainerView's but this seems to be presenting me with a whole load of "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" errors.

Am I going about this in the correct way? Has anyone tried to do something similar and succeeded?

Thanks, Joe

Comment: It sounds OK in theory.  (I've done it with top, bottom, leading, and trailing.)  You may have to look at which constraints are reporting conflicts.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into that.

Comment: Alright, this is really weird but it sorted its self out after I updated the frames in the view in interface builder. Bizarre and I don't understand why it's changed now but it has. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set equal width and equal height constraints. If this does not solve your problem, you need to tell which constraints exactly are conflicting.

Comment: Yeah, i'll check that out. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, It's sorted now as i wrote in the comments above.